# How do I get to see my Mode 06 in OBDii

Tags: obd-ii

Mode 06 in OBD2 is good to get an insight of what faults the car might encounter in the future.
But I am unable to find out what command should I send to get Mode 06 data. It has TID$01 CID$01, so how do I send the command? 060101 or 0601?
Please help.

Also how do I decode the information? It is not fixed for all manufacturers, then how does Torque Pro app say MID$01 TID$01 is O2 Bank1 Sensor1?

Car: 2010 Hyundai i10 Era (Petrol)

Sending 0600 command, I received:

```
7E8 06 46 00 80 00 00 01
```

Sending 0601 command, I received:

```
7E8 10 37 46 01 01 0A 0E 66 
7E8 21 0E 66 0E 66 01 02 0A 
7E8 22 0E 66 0E 66 0E 66 01 
7E8 23 07 0A 00 00 00 00 0C 
7E8 24 D8 01 08 0A 1D 70 13 
7E8 25 18 22 90 01 09 10 00 
7E8 26 78 00 78 05 F0 01 0A 
7E8 27 10 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

Sending 0605 command, I received:

```
7E8 10 0B 46 00 80 00 00 01 
7E8 21 00 80 00 00 01 00 00
```

For any other 06xx command (including 060101, i.e. Mode 06 TID 01 CID 01), I get "NO DATA".
Please help me decode the above data.

Comment: I think the first 4 are the CID and the last 4 are the result. AFAIK you need a list of Hyundais TIDs to really know what test is what.

Comment: 7E8 10 37 46 01 01 0A 0E 66 
7E8 21 0E 66 0E 66 01 02 0A 
7E8 22 0E 66 0E 66 0E 66 01 
7E8 23 07 0A 00 00 00 00 0C 
7E8 24 D8 01 08 0A 1D 70 13 
7E8 25 18 22 90 01 09 10 01 
7E8 26 40 00 78 05 F0 01 0A 
7E8 27 10 02 94 00 C8 09 C4.      this is mode 06 mid 01 response for  Hyundaii10.... Please tell me the way to decide this hex string, the method

Comment: 7E8 10 13 46 81 80 AF FF B9 
7E8 21 FD 12 02 EE 81 82 05 
7E8 22 81 CA 62 8F 9D 71 00.   this  is mode 06 mid 81 response for the same car above

Comment: Do you have a link to the OBDii specification that shows the format of these messages? I get the feeling this is a manufacturer specific set of fields, but it would be a good place to start.

Comment: @cdunn mode 6 is manufacturer specific you need access to whatever subscription they require of you to access the lists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an analysis of your result:

`0600 => 7E8 06 46 00 80 00 00 01`

This is the usual query to check with PIDs (or MIDs as they are called in mode 6 for CAN) are supported. In your case it says, bit 1 and bit 32 are supported, hence commands `0601`and `0620` can be tried. `0605` is obviously not supported, hence the result is undefined (and, frankly `7E8 10 0B 46 00 80 00 00 01 7E8 21 00 80 00 00 01 00 00`, does not look like a proper result for `0605` anyways. I would have expected `NO DATA`).

Now to the actual data. Your result was

```
7E8 10 37 46 01 01 0A 0E 66 
7E8 21 0E 66 0E 66 01 02 0A 
7E8 22 0E 66 0E 66 0E 66 01 
7E8 23 07 0A 00 00 00 00 0C 
7E8 24 D8 01 08 0A 1D 70 13 
7E8 25 18 22 90 01 09 10 00 
7E8 26 78 00 78 05 F0 01 0A 
7E8 27 10 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

Let me remove the address header and multiframing, then we get the following:

```
01 01 0A 0E 66 0E 66 0E 66
01 02 0A 0E 66 0E 66 0E 66
01 07 0A 00 00 00 00 0C D8
01 08 0A 1D 70 13 18 22 90
01 09 10 00 78 00 78 05 F0
01 0A 10 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

which looks like 6 test results à 9 bytes, which is correct so far. I have added explanation headers to the fourth test result:

```
MID TID UASID  VHI VLO  MINHI MINLO MAXHI MAXLO
01  08  0A     1D  70   13    18    22    90
```

MID `01` means you get exactly what you have asked for with `0601`, which according to SAE1979(DA) is the result for the "exhaust gas sensor monitor bank 1 - sensor 1`.

TID `08` means "Maximum sensor voltage for test cycle". UASID `0A` is the unit and scaling definition and means "Voltage" and "0.122 mV per bit unsigned".

VHI/LO is used to compute the actual test value, which results in

```
( 0x1d * 0x100 + 0x70 ) * 0.122 = 919.392
```

The minimum and maximum is computed accordingly hence results in a minimum of `596.336` and a maximum of `1079.456`, which means this test has passed (yay!).

I have fed your information into my [OBD2 iOS App](https://itunes.apple.com/de/app/obd2-expert/id1142156521?mt=8) where I'm working on MODE 6 diagnostics as we speak. Here is a screenshot of the result:

[image: OBD2 Expert Component Monitoring Mode 6 Diagnostics]

Comment: That is an awesome piece of knowledge! So you basically converted the hex to decimal and multiplied by the factor. I have a doubt: how can you figure out if the hex to decimal conversion should lead to a negative number? I mean any hex I convert to decimal I get a positive result, how will I know if the value can/should be a negative one? Is there any bit in the data for that?

Comment: @SoumyaSen yes, the UASID (Unit and Scaling) byte has about a hundred SAE-definitions. SAE J1979DA contains a map and for every entry there is a name, a unit specification, and multiplier, a linear offset, and whether the value is to be treated as signed or unsigned, e.g.:

Voltage, mV, 0.1 mV per bit, unsigned, -3276.8

Answer (score 3):

Mode 6 decode algorithms and databases, to the best of my knowledge, are only available to those scan tool makers who subscribe to the NASTF system.
[NASTF.org](http://www.nastf.org/i4a/pages/index.cfm?pageid=1)
 This is an industry organization that acts a go between the OEM's and the tool makers. Many tool makers are not members and those who make clones are not accepted into the group.

Mode 6 data is not standardized in any way, every OEM reports the data differently. Some report lots of data for every model, others, very little. As with everything scan data it changes, and gets better as OBD11 matured. It was not required to be accurate until 2006. Before that it is very spotty.

The OEM tech websites that I have access to do not have Mode 6 decode data.
Some scanners are much better than others at decoding and presenting the data. The best generic I have seen is the scanner made by Automotive Test Solutions. I have not found a cheap scanner that does this well.

Ford does a great job with Mode 6 and even adds some neat features like a misfire graph.

Answer (score 1):

I was checking out mode 6. Here is a link that might help.
**http://www.counterman.com/unlock-the-mysteries-of-mode-06/**
It is extremely difficult to find exact info on mode 6 data as the manufacturers seem to be secretive about it. The closest I got for Hyundai was this link where you ask technicians questions (and probably pay through the nose for it). **www.justanswer.com › Car Questions › Hyundai Repair**

Comment: Another site to try would be hyundaitechinfo.com I forget if it's free or not.

Comment: @Ben: just checked the site. I think it is for Hyundai dealers not the general public...Of course I could be wrong. Have you tried to get an account with that website?

Comment: It turns out the account creation is free but requires a paid subscription to actually view content. Either way I think he's going to have to pay some money to be able to decode the test ids and results.

Comment: @Ben: I agree....